# null pointer exception string builder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am trying to use the setCharAt method in a StringBuilder but I am getting a null pointer exception.  Is there a way I can add values to the StringBuilder array I have made so I wont get these error.

From research I have found the .append() method but I'm not even sure how it works.

```
import java.util.*;  // Allows for the input of a scanner method.
import java.io.*;    // Allows for the inputting and outputting of a data file.
import java.lang.*;  // Allows for the use of String Methods.
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class TESTY
{
static Scanner testanswers;
static PrintWriter testresults;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    testanswers = new Scanner(new FileReader("TestInput.dat"));
    testresults = new PrintWriter("TestOutput.dat");

    String StudentID;
    String answers;
    // Reads first two lines first to know how many records there are.
    String answerKey = testanswers.nextLine();
    int count = Integer.parseInt(testanswers.nextLine());

    // Allocate the array for the size needed.
    String[][] answerArray = new String[count][];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        String line = testanswers.nextLine();
        answerArray[i] = line.split(" ", 2);
    }

    for(int row = 0; row < answerArray.length; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < answerArray[row].length; col++)
        {
            System.out.print(answerArray[row][col] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }   
    gradeData(answerArray, answerKey);




    testanswers.close();
    testresults.close();

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Method: gradeData
//Description: This method will grade testanswers showing 
//what was missed, skipped, letter grade, and percentage.
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static double gradeData(String[][] answerArray, String answerKey)
{   

    String key = answerKey;
    double Points = 0;
    StringBuilder[] wrongAnswers = new StringBuilder[5];
    String studAnswers;

    for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < answerArray.length; rowIndex++)   /// Counting rows
    {
        studAnswers = answerArray[rowIndex][1].replace(" ", "S");  ///Counts rows, Col stay static index 1
        for(int charIndex = 0; charIndex < studAnswers.length(); charIndex++) 
        {
            if(studAnswers.charAt(charIndex) == key.charAt(charIndex))
            {
                Points += 2;
            }
            else if(studAnswers.charAt(charIndex) == 'S')
            {
                Points --;
            }
            else if(studAnswers.charAt(charIndex) != key.charAt(charIndex))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < wrongAnswers.length; i++)
                {

                    wrongAnswers[i].setCharAt(charIndex, 'X');
                }
                Points -= 2;                        
            }

        }
        System.out.println(Points);
    }

    return Points;


}
```

}

The error is occurring on line 91 :

```
wrongAnswers[i].setCharAt(charIndex, 'X');
```

Comment: `wrongAnswers[i]` is `null`. Initialize it first.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared an array of `StringBuilder`s, but you haven't initialized any of the slots, so they're still `null`.

Initialize them:

```
StringBuilder[] wrongAnswers = new StringBuilder[5];
for (int i = 0; i < wrongAnswers.length; i++)
{
    wrongAnswers[i] = new StringBuilder();
}
```

Additionally, using `setCharAt` won't work here, because initially, there is nothing in the `StringBuilder`.  Depending on what you want here, you may need to just call `append`, or you may initially want a string full of spaces so that you can set a specific character to `'X'`.

Comment: After comparing my studAnswers to key, I am wanting something that will make an array of 5 elements that will replace the specific character index of an element with 'X' permitting studAnswers and key are not equal.

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder[] wrongAnswers = new StringBuilder[5];`

does not create 5 empty StringBuilders but 5 null StringBuilders.

You need to call something like

`wrongAnswers[i] = new StringBuilder()`

in order to initialize your 5 array members.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that

```
StringBuilder[] wrongAnswers = new StringBuilder[5];
```

does not create 5 `StringBuilder` objects.  It only creates an array with 5 null `StringBuilder` references.  You need to create each `StringBuilder` separately with a line such as

```
wrongAnswers[i] = new StringBuilder();
```

inside a loop over `i`.